# Datepicker in bootstrap and booked dates and times

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i want to use bootstrap's datepicker in my form, but i need to show also already booked schedules (maybe marked as red or whatever) to avoid that the user make some reservation on already planned date.

Is this possible?

I read that datepicker has something like **datesDisabled** option, but does it work also for specified time ranges od the day? For example the user is choosing the 22.06.2015 and see that on this day, times from 10:00 to 12:00 and from 14:00 to 15:30 are already not available, so he can't choose it anymore.

Thanks for any help

Regards

Comment: Can you link to which plugin you are using. There is more than one.

Comment: i mean this plugin https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/